# Intermediate value theorem with switch of order of integration and differentiation

Tags: integration, limits, partial-differential-equations, continuity, systems-of-equations

$$  f \left( x,y \right) ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{continuous at area} ~D ~ \text{and differentiable by 1st order of  } ~y $$

$$  \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left( \int_{a }^{b } f\left(x,y\right)  \,dx   \right) = \int_{a }^{b } \frac{\partial}{\partial y }\left( f\left(x,y\right)  \right)   \,dx~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{what I want to derive it finally}     $$

$$  F \left( y \right):=\int_{a}^{b}f\left(x,y\right)\,dx$$

$$  \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left( \int_{a }^{b } f\left(x,y\right)  \,dx   \right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left( F(y) \right)  $$

$$ = \lim_{ k \to 0}  \frac{  F(y+k) -F(y) }{  k  }  $$

$$ = \lim_{ k \to 0} \frac{  \int_{a}^{b}f\left(x,y+k\right)\,dx-\int_{a}^{b}f\left(x,y\right)\,dx  }{  k  }  $$

$$ = \lim_{ k \to 0}  \frac{1}{ k }   \int_{a}^{b} \left\{ f\left(x,y+k\right)-f\left(x,y\right) \right\}  \,dx    $$

$$  f_{y}\left(x,y\right) :=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left( f\left(x,y\right)  \right)  $$

$$  f\left(x,y+k\right) -f\left(x,y\right) =f_{y}\left(x,y+ \theta_{}k \right) k ~~\leftrightarrow~~  \left( 0< \theta_{} <1 \right) \tag{1}  $$

The eqn1 can be held via intermediate value theorem, but, currently I can't relate them. I need some your hints.

[image]

[Quoted the above image from wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem)

Comment: it's not by the intermediate value theorem, it's by the mean-value theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$  f\left(x,y+k\right) -f\left(x,y\right) =f_{y}\left(x,y+ \theta_{}k \right) k ~~\leftrightarrow~~  \left( 0< \theta_{} <1 \right) \tag{1}  $$

$$  \frac{  f\left(x,y+k\right) -f\left(x,y\right)  }{  k  } = f_{y}\left(x,y+ \theta_{}k \right) ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{Transformed eqn1}   $$

The above equation is of [a mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) ,not a intermediate value theorem.

$~y+ \theta_{}k ~$can be included in the opened section$~~(y,y+k) ~$